# Poisson to Normal distribution

Tags: probability

The number of Hira per minute on a website has a Poisson distribution with mean 0.8. The time between successive hits is denoted by T minutes. 
By showing $P(T>t)=e^{-0.8t}$ (done) find the probability that the time interval between 1st and 51st hit exceeds one hour.

$T=N(48,48)$

$$P(1.5≤T≤50.5)=
P(T≤50.5)-(P(T≤1.5))$$

$$P(T≤50.5)-P(T≤1.5)=0.641$$

Which is wrong.
Can somebody please tell me the flaw in my answer?

Comment: Do you know the correct solution ?

Answer (score 0):

It's wrong because after every hit the process resets. You are calculating the probability of the time being between 1 and 51 minutes for the next hit, whereas the question tells you that hit 51 occurs more than an hour after the 1st hit. So this is equivalent to calculating :

$$P(\mbox{hits}\leq 49\mbox{ in one hour})=\sum_{r=0}^{49}\frac{1}{e^{\lambda t}}\frac{(\lambda t)^{r}}{r!},$$

where $\lambda=0.8$ and $t=60$.

Comment: Can you use a normal approximation to solve this?(Because I cannot calculate that sum manually) and the answer is 0.614 whereas the sum gives 0.5945.

Comment: Use $\le 50 hits$ instead of $49$ I think it will get you the correct solution.

Comment: @FaiqRaees: So with $x=50$ hits and a normal approximation of $P(X\leq x)\approx F_{normal}(\mu=0.8\cdot 60,\sigma^2=0.8\cdot 60,x)$ I get 0.614

Comment: @Furrane: maybe I'm just being dense here but it says that it's between the first and 51st hit. That means the process resets so we want an hour of separation on 50 hits. But then we'd need $P(\mbox{hits}<50)$ to be strictly above an hour, right?

Comment: @AlexR. To be honest mate I always hate those specific kind of questions (like n things separated by n-1 spaces) but given the result you got I supposed it might be that kind of mistake. If you land on the correct solution with $P(hits\le 50)$ then it might very well be it. But once again those kind of details always trigger me =)

Comment: @AlexR. Why are we not applying continuity correction since the variables go from discrete to continuous?

Comment: @FaiqRaees: You can apply the continuity correction of $0.5$; I was just trying to recreate the supposed true answer by fiddling with the normal distribution.

Answer (score 0):

There are a couple of approaches:

- The time between the $1$st and $51$st hits has a Gamma distribution. Using the following R code `1 - pgamma(60, shape=50, rate=0.8)` gives $0.5946$
- The number of hits in an hour has a Poisson distribution with rate $0.8\times 60=48$.  Using the following R code `ppois(50-1, lambda=0.8*60)` also gives $0.5946$

So this seems to be the actual value.

Using a normal approximation to these two calculations (including a continuity correction for the discrete Poisson but not for the continuous Gamma distribution) might suggest respectively

- `1 - pnorm( (60 - 50/0.8) / sqrt(50/0.8^2) )` giving $0.6114$
- `pnorm( (49.5 - 60*0.8) / sqrt(60*0.8) )` giving $0.5857$

neither of which are as close as I would like, though their average is not bad

Without the continuity correction, the last becomes `pnorm( (49 - 60*0.8) / sqrt(60*0.8) )` giving $0.5574$, or `pnorm( (50 - 60*0.8) / sqrt(60*0.8) )` giving $0.6136$ with this final number being the answer you have seen rounded to $0.614$